# MouseClick event not fired for disabled or read-only fields?

Tags: .net, events, readonly, mouseclick-event

I'm using .NET C# there. I have a textbox. I assigned it a MouseClick event.

Normally the event is fired when I click the control.

But if I set the textbox's [**Enabled=false**] or [**ReadOnly=true**] properties, the MouseClick event is not fired.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: It won't fire if you set Enabled = false, that's by design.  It *will* fire if you set ReadOnly = true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearly disabling the control is the issue, you could leave it enabled and not read-only then in the KeyPress/KeyDown event you avoid/cancel any input so the user cannot change the content.

Comment: Thank you, Hans and Davide... That takes care of the textbox. Is there a way we can accomplish the same "ReadOnly" for ComboBoxes and RadioButtons? They don't seem to have a readonly property.

Comment: RadioButtons have [AutoCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.autocheck.aspx) property